# Timestamp is no longer supported error when creating a new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to ask a question abou the error I am getting here. I am trying to create a new column that intiate a position if the price of tomorrow is predicted higher than today using the following code. it is giving me the error:

> TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

```
new= pd.DataFrame(index=x_valid.index)

new['Shares'] = [1 if x_valid[i+1] > x_valid[i] else 0 for i in new.index]
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-5e7800e6d5ce> in <module>()
      2 new= pd.DataFrame(index=x_valid.index)
      3 
----> 4 new['Shares'] = [1 if x_valid[i+1]>x_valid[i] else 0 for i in new.index]

<ipython-input-92-5e7800e6d5ce> in <listcomp>(.0)
      2 new= pd.DataFrame(index=x_valid.index)
      3 
----> 4 new['Shares'] = [1 if x_valid[i+1]>x_valid[i] else 0 for i in new.index]

pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._Timestamp.__add__()

TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`
```

Any insights would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When you used the list comprehension, the `i`, in that particular case, is a `Timestamp` from the `DatetimeIndex`. Consequently, when you add 1 to get the next `row` the `TypeError` arises.

```py
print(df[df.index[0] + 1])
```

> TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

A easier way to compare row values is using the [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) command to dislocate the index by a desired number of periods (positive or negative). In this case comparing today's price with the previous day (`df['Price'] > df['Price'].shift()`)

*Setup*

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([10, 20, 15, 25, 40], columns=['Price'])
df.index = pd.date_range(start='01/01/2021', periods=5, freq='1D')
print(df)

#             Price
# 2020-01-01     10
# 2020-01-02     20
# 2020-01-03     15
# 2020-01-04     25
# 2020-01-05     40
```

```py
df['Shares'] = (df['Price'] > df['Price'].shift()).astype(int)
```

```
            Price  Shares
2020-01-01     10       0
2020-01-02     20       1
2020-01-03     15       0
2020-01-04     25       1
2020-01-05     40       1
```